# Merging rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, merge, survey

I am trying to merge 3 rows in to 1 based on multiple conditions. The dataframe is created as follows:

```
region <- c("Europe", "Asia", "Europe", "Africa","Europe")
enterprise <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
q1 <- c(NA, 0, NA, 1, 0)
q2 <- c(0, 1, 1, NA, NA)
q3 <- c(NA, 1, NA, 0, NA)
q4 <- c(NA, 0, 1, 0, 0)
q5 <- c(0,NA,1,NA,1)

df <- data.frame(region, enterprise, q1, q2, q3, q4,q5)
```

So, I'm working with survey data and I'm trying to merge rows corresponding to region 'Europe' in to one row. Conditions are as follows:

1. For any given question, the most complete source should be used. For example, if enterprise 2 and 3 (For Europe region) have NA for q1 (haven't answered the question) but enterprise 1 have an answer (either 0 or 1) then answer of enterprise 1 should be considered.
2. If all 3 enterprises haven't answered (NA) then NA.
3. In case more than 1 enterprises per region give complete answers (0 or 1) then the following enterprise hierarchy should be followed in order to chose the enterprise and its answer to include in the final merged row. Enterprise 1 has highest level in hierarchy followed by enterprise 2 and 3. For example, enterprise 1 hasn't answered the question (NA) but 2 and 3 did. Then answer of enterprise 2 should be considered.
4. If all 3 enterprises have answered, then hierarchical order should be followed again.

I have tried using

```
merged = coalesce(df[1,],df[3,],df[5,])
```

But couldn't get it to work. I don't know how to pass conditions especially the one with hierarchies. My desired output is as follows:

```
  region q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1   Asia  0  1  1  0 NA
2 Africa  1 NA  0  0 NA
3 Europe  0  0 NA  1  0
```

Thank you very much for any help, beforehand.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could change your example so that we could test all of your conditions. Currently, your example would already give the desired result after checking for condition 1. please provide more cases where condition 2 and 3 would need to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  fill(q1:q5, .direction="updown") %>% 
  arrange(enterprise) %>% 
  summarise(across(q1:q5, ~ .x[1]))
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  region    q1    q2    q3    q4    q5
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Africa     1    NA     0     0    NA
2 Asia       0     1     1     0    NA
3 Europe     0     0    NA     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Can you please explain summarise(across(q1:q5, ~ .x[1])) part a little? Also how did you implemented hierarchy condition?

Comment: @dryl Sure. `fill` guarantees that you always have a value (if present in group). `arrange` makes sure that the enterprises are in the right order for the following `summarise`, which picks the first value across all marked columns. Since `fill` and `arrange` already did their job this should always be the desired value.

Comment: Thank you very much, this clears up everything for me. Sorry to bother you, I have one more question, how I can alter the output if hierarchical order of enterprises should be different for specific column. Lets say for column q2, enterprise 3 should be first in hierarchical order, enterprise 2 should be second and enterprise 1 should be 3rd.

Comment: @dryl You can do something like this: `df %>% group_by(region) %>% fill(q1:q5, .direction="updown") %>% arrange(sd=enterprise) %>% summarise(across(-c(enterprise, q2), ~ first(.x)), q2 = last(q2))`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

region <- c("Europe", "Asia", "Europe", "Africa","Europe")
enterprise <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
q1 <- c(1, 0, NA, 1, NA)
q2 <- c(0, 1, 1, NA, NA)
q3 <- c(NA, 1, NA, 0, NA)
q4 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0)

df <- data.frame(region, enterprise, q1, q2, q3, q4)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(q1:q4, names_to="q", values_to="vals") %>% 
  group_by(region, q) %>% 
  mutate(ind = min(enterprise[which(!is.na(vals))])) %>% 
  filter(enterprise == ind) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = "vals", names_from = "q") %>% 
  select(region, q1, q2, q3, q4)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#> # Groups:   region [3]
#>   region    q1    q2    q3    q4
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Europe     1     0    NA     1
#> 2 Asia       0     1     1     0
#> 3 Africa     1    NA     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>